# Expand each summary row of a data frame into a type-count

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this, with two key columns and then a count of things that come in three different types.

```
  Year Month Urban Suburban Rural
1    1     1    11       12    13
2    1     2    21       22    23
```

I want to expand each row so that it lists the type as a factor and then the number in that type, so something like this:

```
  Year Month     Type Number
1    1     1    Urban     11
2    1     1 Suburban     12
3    1     1    Rural     13
4    1     2    Urban     21
5    1     2 Suburban     22
6    1     2    Rural     23
```

is there a function that does this painlessly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely what the `reshape` and `reshape2` packages are designed to do:

```
require(reshape2)
x <- read.table(text = "Year Month Urban Suburban Rural
1    1     1    11       12    13
2    1     2    21       22    23")

#Specify the variables that are your ID variables. The others will form your "long" data
x.m <- melt(x, id.vars = c("Year", "Month"))
#-----  
Year Month variable value
1    1     1    Urban    11
2    1     2    Urban    21
3    1     1 Suburban    12
...
```

There is a paper in the [journal of statistical software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12) that's a great place to get started.

Comment: What is the difference between the `reshape` and `reshape2` packages?

Comment: @BlueMagister - reshape2 was a pretty big rewrite of the original code as the author learned more about programming, etc. He improved speed and some functionality in the second iteration, but did not want to lose some of the compatibility with the older functions. He explains a lot more about this here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-pkgs-reshape2-a-reboot-of-the-reshape-package-td2534378.html. For most purposes, using reshape2 should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
dat <- read.table(text=" Year Month Urban Suburban Rural
 1    1     1    11       12    13
 2    1     2    21       22    23
 ", header=TRUE)

reshape(dat, direction="long", idvar=1:2, varying=names(dat)[3:5], times=names(dat)[3:5], v.names="Number", timevar="Type")
             Year Month     Type Number
1.1.Urban       1     1    Urban     11
1.2.Urban       1     2    Urban     21
1.1.Suburban    1     1 Suburban     12
1.2.Suburban    1     2 Suburban     22
1.1.Rural       1     1    Rural     13
1.2.Rural       1     2    Rural     23
```

(Note that the `reshape` function is in the standard set of packages and not in the reshape or resshape2 packages.)